# Use position_jitterdodge to plot points, and add highlighted points that are also dodged

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data where `x` is categorical, `y` is numeric, and `color.var` is another categorical variable that I would like to color by. My goal is to plot all of the points using `position_jitterdodge()`, and then highlight a couple of the points, draw a line between them, and add labels, while making sure these highlighted points line up with the corresponding strips of points that were plotted using `position_jitterdodge()`. The highlighted points are aligned properly when all factors are present in the variable used to dodge, but it does not work well when some factors are missing.

### Minimal (non-)working example

```
library(ggplot2)
```

#### Generate some data

```
d = data.frame(x = c(rep('x1', 1000), rep('x2', 1000)), 
               y = runif(n=2000, min=0, max=1), 
               color.var= rep(c('color1', 'color2'), 1000), 
               facet.var = rep(c('facet1', 'facet1', 'facet2', 'facet2'), 500))
head(d)
dd = d[c(1,2,3,4,1997,1998, 1999,2000),]
dd
df1 = dd[dd$color.var=='color1',] ## data for first  set of points, labels, and the line connecting them
df2 = dd[dd$color.var=='color2',] ## data for second set of points, labels, and the line connecting them
df1
dw = .75 ## Define the dodge.width
```

#### Plot all points

Here are all of the points, separated using `position_jitterdodge()` and the aesthetic fill.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=color.var), position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=dw), size=3, alpha=1, shape=21, color='darkgray') + 
  facet_wrap(~facet.var) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c( 'lightblue','gray'))+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]

That works well.

#### Additional highlighted points.

Here is the same plot, with additional points in `dd` added.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=d,  aes(x=x, y=y, fill =color.var), position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=dw), size=3, alpha=1, shape=21, color='darkgray') + 
  geom_point(data=dd, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var                                   ), position=position_dodge(width=.75), size=4   ) +
   geom_line(data=dd, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var, group=color.var                  ), position=position_dodge(width=.75), size=1   ) +
  geom_label(data=dd, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var, group=color.var, label=round(y,1)), position=position_dodge(width=.75), vjust=-.5) + 
  facet_wrap(~facet.var) +   
  scale_fill_manual(values=c( 'lightblue','gray'))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c( 'blue', 'gray40')) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]

This is what I want it to look like. However, this only works properly if both factors of the `color.var` variable are in the set of points to highlight.
If both factors aren't present in the new data, the horizonal alignment fails.

#### Highlight points, only one factor present

Here is an example where only the 'color1' factor (blue) is present. Note that `data=dd` was replaced with `data=df1` (data that only contains blue highlighted dots) in this code.

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data=d,  aes(x=x, y=y, fill =color.var), position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=dw), size=3, alpha=1, shape=21, color='darkgray') + 
      geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var                                   ), position=position_dodge(width=.75), size=4   ) +
       geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var, group=color.var                  ), position=position_dodge(width=.75), size=1   ) +
      geom_label(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var, group=color.var, label=round(y,1)), position=position_dodge(width=.75), vjust=-.5) + 
      facet_wrap(~facet.var) +   
      scale_fill_manual(values=c( 'lightblue','gray'))+
      scale_color_manual(values=c( 'blue', 'gray40')) +
      theme(axis.title = element_blank())+
      theme(legend.position="top") +
      scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
```

[image]

The highlight blue dots appear between the blue and gray dots, instead of aligned with the blue dots. Note that the additional code  `scale_x_discrete(drop=F)` had no apparent effect on the alignment.

#### A manual solution

One possible fix is to edit the `x` coordinate manually, like this

```
 ggplot(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
      geom_point(aes(fill=color.var), position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=dw), size=3, alpha=1, shape=21, color='darkgray') + 
      geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=as.numeric(x)-dw/4, y=y), alpha=.9, size=4 , color='blue') +            ## first set of points
      geom_line( data=df1, aes(x=as.numeric(x)-dw/4, y=y , group=color.var     ), color='blue', size=1) +    ## first line
      geom_label(data=df1, aes(x=as.numeric(x)-dw/4, y=y , label=round(y,1)), color='blue', vjust=-.25)+ ## first set of labels
      facet_wrap(~facet.var) +   
      scale_fill_manual(values=c( 'lightblue','gray'))+
      theme(axis.title = element_blank() +
      theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]

An adjustment of 1/4 of the `dodge.width` seems to work.  This works fine, but it seems like there should be a better way, especially since I will eventually want to do this with 4-5 sets of highlighted points/lines, which may all be all be the same `color.var`, like the blue 'color1' factor above.  Repeating this 4-5 times would be cumbersome. I will also eventually want to do this will 5-10 different figures. I suppose `dodge.width`*1/4 will always work, and copying and pasting might do the trick, but would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: One option to take advantage of dodging is to add rows in the dataset for all levels of the dodging factor (based on `color` in this case).  This would mean expanding the dataset.  For example, with *tidyr* / *dplyr* you could expand the dataset via `df1 %>% group_by(facet.var, x) %>% complete(color.var)`

Comment: Thanks @aosmith, works like a charm.  Just added an Answer with that line of code along with ggplot stuff from the question.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on @aosmith's comment.  Basically, just need to add this code before using `ggplot`:

```
library(dplyr) ## needed for group_by()
library(tidyr) ## needed for complete()
df1 = df1 %>% group_by(facet.var, x) %>% complete(color.var)
```

That adds extra rows to the data so that all the levels of `color.var` are present. Then the code given in the question, along with a couple of small edits that fix the legend, can be used:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=d  , aes(x=x, y=y, fill =color.var), position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=dw), size=3, alpha=1, shape=21, color='darkgray', show.legend=T) + 
  geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var                                   ), position=position_dodge(width=.75), size=4, show.legend=T   ) +
  geom_line( data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var, group=color.var                  ), position=position_dodge(width=.75), size=1, show.legend=F   ) +
  geom_label(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y, color=color.var, group=color.var, label=round(y,1)), position=position_dodge(width=.75), vjust=-.5, show.legend=F) + 
  facet_wrap(~facet.var) +   
  scale_fill_manual( values=c( 'lightblue','gray'), name='Background dots', guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(color=c('lightblue', 'gray')))) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c( 'blue', 'gray40')  , name='Highlighted dots') +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
```